# sql query for getting count of column related to other mapping entries in more than one table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

i have following table in mysql table

a_ad_display

```
╔═══════╦══════════╗
║ ADVID ║ ADTYPEID ║
╠═══════╬══════════╣
║     1 ║        1 ║
║     2 ║        1 ║
║     3 ║        4 ║
║     3 ║        3 ║
║     2 ║        2 ║
║     1 ║        4 ║
║     1 ║        3 ║
║     4 ║        1 ║
║     4 ║        1 ║
╚═══════╩══════════╝
```

a_mediatype

```
╔═════════╦═══════════╗
║ MEDIAID ║ MEDIANAME ║
╠═════════╬═══════════╣
║       1 ║ Animation ║
║       2 ║ video     ║
║       3 ║ Image     ║
╚═════════╩═══════════╝
```

a_ad_type

```
╔══════════╦════════╗
║ ADTYPEID ║ ADTYPE ║
╠══════════╬════════╣
║        1 ║ e Ad   ║
║        2 ║ b Ad   ║
║        3 ║ c Ad   ║
║        4 ║ d Ad   ║
╚══════════╩════════╝
```

a_advertise

```
╔═══════╦═════════╗
║ ADVID ║ MEDIAID ║
╠═══════╬═════════╣
║     1 ║       1 ║
║     2 ║       1 ║
║     3 ║       2 ║
║     4 ║       3 ║
╚═══════╩═════════╝
```

Now what i want to fetch is as follows...

```
adType  | Image | video  | Animation
eAd     |    0  |    2   |    2 ...
b Ad    |...
c Ad    |...
d Ad    |.....
```

and like wise for all adtype i want data..can anyone please guide me for this...

Ths is what i have tried...

```
SELECT Distinct
at.adtype,
COUNT(IF(am.medianame = 'Animation',1,0)) AS Animation,
COUNT(IF(am.medianame = 'Video',1,0)) AS Video,
COUNT(IF(am.medianame = 'Image',1,0)) AS Image
FROM a_ad_type as at
LEFT JOIN a_ad_display as ad ON at.adtypeId = ad.adtypeId
LEFT JOIN a_advertise as adv ON adv.advertiseId = ad.advId
LEFT JOIN a_mediatype as am ON am.mediaId = adv.mediaTypeId
GROUP BY at.adtype
```

Comment: how are the tables related with each other?

Comment: This is not the way to ask a question. Do you know about sql join? What is your background? What have you tried?

Comment: please see my upadated question...with my old query..which not givng me proper result

Comment: now is it ok????@jurgenrezza

Comment: @BhavikKama Yes it's better. Always include what you have tried and the result you got and why it is not what you want. Now we know that you should use SUM instead of COUNT and CASE WHEN instead of IF and you are good to go.

Comment: ok..thanks for informing me...will keep in mind olways

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT  a.adtype,
        SUM(CASE WHEN d.medianame = 'Image' THEN  1 ELSE 0 END) `Image`,
        SUM(CASE WHEN d.medianame = 'video' THEN  1 ELSE 0 END) `video`,
        SUM(CASE WHEN d.medianame = 'Animation' THEN  1 ELSE 0 END) `Animation`
FROM    a_ad_type a
        LEFT JOIN a_ad_display b
            ON a.adtypeId = b.adtypeId
        LEFT JOIN  a_advertise c
            ON b.advId = c.advId
        LEFT JOIN a_mediatype d
            ON c.mediaId = d.mediaId
GROUP   BY a.adtype
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/759dc/6)

**UPDATE 1**

if you have multiple values of `medianame` and you don;t want it to specify one by one. You can create *Dynamic SQL8 for that,

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'SUM(CASE WHEN d.medianame = ''',
      medianame,
      ''' then 1 ELSE 0 end) AS `',medianame,'`'
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM a_mediatype;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT   a.adtype, ', @sql, ' 
                  FROM  a_ad_type a
                          LEFT JOIN a_ad_display b
                              ON a.adtypeId = b.adtypeId
                          LEFT JOIN  a_advertise c
                              ON b.advId = c.advId
                          LEFT JOIN a_mediatype d
                              ON c.mediaId = d.mediaId
                  GROUP   BY a.adtype');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/759dc/10)

Comment: can u please see my query as i have answered...if its better or nt?

Comment: there's no problem with it but it's static. It will not be flexible if you have multiple values on table `medianame`.

Answer (score 2):

```
 SELECT Distinct
at.adtype,

COUNT(CASE am.mediaId WHEN 1 THEN at.adtypeId END) As Animation,
COUNT(CASE am.mediaId WHEN 2 THEN at.adtypeId END) As Video,
COUNT(CASE am.mediaId WHEN 3 THEN at.adtypeId END) As Image
FROM a_ad_type as at
LEFT JOIN a_ad_display as ad ON at.adtypeId = ad.adtypeId
LEFT JOIN a_advertise as adv ON adv.advertiseId = ad.advId
LEFT JOIN a_mediatype as am ON am.mediaId = adv.mediaTypeId
GROUP BY at.adtype
```

this is the way i got solved my problem..if any one found it wrong then please correct me..thank you

Comment: you can already omit the keyword `DISTINCT` since you are already grouping it by `at.adtype`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to join your tables using the common columns like

```
SELECT ad.adtype
      ,am.medianame
FROM   a_ad_type ad
       INNER JOIN
       a_ad_display add ON ad.adTypeId=add.adTypeId
       INNER JOIN
       a_advertise a ON add.advId=a.advId
       INNER JOIN
       a_mediatype am ON am.mediaId=a.mediaId
```

then you need to pivot the result of this query. Pivoting is database specific syntax and I am unfamiliar with how to do it in mysql (and I allways need to look it up in SQL Server!) but if you search for it I am sure you will find it.

Comment: thanx mite...but i want count of medianame in horizontal way...as i shon in my question at the last table..please see my answer too..i have solved with this..pelase check it..if m wrong then pelase correct me